# Ajax is not aborting when button was clicked

Tags: javascript, ajax, abort

How can I abort an ajax request when a button was clicked? I tried some answers I found here but it didn't work on me.

```
<button type="button" id="toStop">Stop</button>
```

When the stop button was clicked ajax isn't aborting.

```
function() {
    var myajaxreq = $.ajax({
        url: myurlhere,
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        success: function(result) {
                            
        }
        beforeSend: function () {
            if(document.getElementById('toStop').clicked == true) {
                myajaxreq.abort();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no "clicked" property and if it would work, you are only going to check it before it is sent.

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate click listener that will abort ajax request. Using beforeSend will not always work.

```
$('#toStop').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // abort here
    // make sure myajaxreq is accessible in this function
    if (myajaxreq) myajaxreq.abort();
});
```